# chimp mail data geting .each rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, mailchimp

data i want to fetch data where REF_CODE will be nill how can i get these fields with loop or .ech

@body={"members"=>[{"merge_fields"=>{"REF_CODE"=>"", "ROOT_URL"=>"ali.com"}}, {"merge_fields"=>{"REF_CODE"=>"12asdja", "ROOT_URL"=>"columbusnaviggator.com"}}, {"merge_fields"=>{"REF_CODE"=>"12asja", "ROOT_URL"=>"columbusnaviggator.com"}}, {"merge_fields"=>{"REF_CODE"=>"12asja", "ROOT_URL"=>"columbusnaviggator.com"}}, {"merge_fields"=>{"REF_CODE"=>"asa12asdja", "ROOT_URL"=>"columbusnaviggator.com"}}, {"merge_fields"=>{"REF_CODE"=>"12assss", "ROOT_URL"=>"columbusnaviggator.com"}}, {"merge_fields"=>{"REF_CODE"=>"e5118ec91d", "ROOT_URL"=>""}}, {"merge_fields"=>{"REF_CODE"=>"d5a20240aa", "ROOT_URL"=>"Columbusnavigator.com"}}, {"merge_fields"=>{"REF_CODE"=>"09896bcf0c", "ROOT_URL"=>"localhost:3000"}}, {"merge_fields"=>{"REF_CODE"=>"b4a4876c09", "ROOT_URL"=>"localhost:3000"}}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@body['members'].select {|a| a['merge_fields']['REF_CODE']== ''}
# [{"merge_fields"=>{"REF_CODE"=>"", "ROOT_URL"=>"ali.com"}}]
```

The above will return array of fields with **nil** REF_CODE

Comment: response.body['members'].first['merge_fields']["REF_CODE"]

Comment: this is the way i did

Comment: what actually you want from the response?

Comment: if you know that first response has `nil ref_code` you can use this `response.body['members'].first['merge_fields']["REF_CODE"]`. If not you can use mine.

Comment: actually that was just testing on rails console :D thats why i write first. else i use each loop and n get all ref codes from the hashes.
By the way thank you so much sir